# Return tuples from a tuple of tuples which contain given text in an element in another tuple

Tags: python, comparison, tuples, python-3.3

I have a tuple of tuples which I've read out of a .csv file, and the individual tuples look like this:

```
("1", "08:15:25", "17161234567")
```

The third element in the tuple is a telephone number, and I've been trying to print tuples that match another tuple of area codes, which looks like this:

```
ac = (212, 312, 716)
```

The code I wrote to try to check this looks like this:

```
def check(tuplename):
    results = []
    for row in tuplename:
        if any(ac in x for x in tuplename):
            results.append(x)
    print(results)
```

The other code I've read seems to be concerned with symmetrical comparison of lists, which doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. The output is an empty list:

```
[]
```

Comment: `results.append(x)` doesn't seem to be indented

Comment: Sorry, it is in my code. I fixed it.

Comment: Do your tuples contain strings? If so you need to show the quotes around them. `08:15:25` is not a valid Python value either, so that item would *have* to be a string.

Comment: And what is `tuplename` here, is that one row from your CSV file? Or is it all rows? If `ac` is a tuple itself, `ac in x` is never going to work.

Comment: Damn, I've just read the title and I guess it's some kind of tuple-ception here...

Comment: Eeep, I hadn't thought of that. The tuples contain strings.

tuplename is all rows. ac is a tuple itself.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to actually extract the area code, which is x[1:4]
Then just check if that is in your area code tuple

assuming: tuplename is a list of these tuples, like so:

```
tuplename = [(1, "08:15:25", "17161234567"), (2, "12:41:08", "12127654321")]
```

then your function would be rewritten as:

```
def check(tuplename):
    results = []
    for row in tuplename:
        tel = row[2] # extract phone number from tuple
        tuple_ac = tel[1:4] # extract area code from phone number
        if tuple_ac in ac:
            results.append(x)
    print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `tuplename` is a sequence of rows, and you want to return matching rows, `check` should be:

```
def check(tuplename):
    return [row for row in tuplename if any(code in row[2] for code in ac)]
```

This tests each item in `ac` against `row[2]`, the phone number column, producing a list of matching rows to return with a list comprehension.

If you feel the list comprehension is not easy to decipher, the equivalent loop version is:

```
def check(tuplename):
    results = []
    for row in tuplename:
        if any(code in row[2] for code in ac):
            results.append(row)
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your area code list is actually strings:

```
rows = [('1', '08:15:25', '17161234567'),
        ('2', '08:15:26', '12121234567'),
        ('3', '08:15:27', '19991234567'),
        ('4', '08:15:28', '13121234567')]
codes = ('212', '312', '716')

for item in (row for row in rows if row[2][1:4] in codes):
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
('1', '08:15:25', '17161234567')
('2', '08:15:26', '12121234567')
('4', '08:15:28', '13121234567')
```